# Is the number $x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x$ divisible for 5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I'm trying to solve this problem.

Is the number $x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x$ (x belonging to $\Bbb Z$) divisible for 5? For which values of x, it is NOT divisible for 30?

My attempt. I tried to answer the first question by finding the equivalent $mod 5$ of each element.

- $x^9$ corresponds to x ($mod5$)
- $2x^7$ corresponds to $2x^3(mod5)$

So by thinking the expression mod5, then $x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x = x+2x^3+3x^3+4x= 5x^3+5x$ which is reasonably a multiple of 5. Is my attempt correct? How can I answer the second question?

Comment: What does $x^9\text{ corresponds to }x\pmod5$ mean?

Comment: Note:  you only need to check for $x=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos For Fermat's Little Theorem $x^4\equiv1(mod5)$ so $x^9\equiv x^5(mod5)\equiv x(mod5)$

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach, and it can be generalized to the same question $\mod p$ where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: @Jack Then your approach is fine.

Comment: Try with $30=3\cdot5\cdot2$ we only need to check for $3$ separately as the expression is even

Comment: And you need only check if $\,3\mid f(1)\,$ since $f(-1) = - f(1)$ by $f$ odd. Similarly for divisor $5$ we need only check $\,5\mid f(1)=10,\,$ and $\,5\mid f(2)\ $ (e.g. using $\,2^4\equiv 1\,$ or $\,2^2\equiv -1,\,$  a special case of what you did)

Comment: @Jack You might find helpful the comment I posted on lhf's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By FLT, $x^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$, so

$$x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x\equiv x+2x^3+3x^3-x\equiv 5x^3\equiv 0\pmod 5$$

so yes, your approach is correct and the expression is divisible by $5$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z$

---

For divisibility by $30$, you need to check divisibility by $6$, ie, by $2$ and $3$. We have,

$$x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x\equiv x+0+3x+0\equiv 4x\equiv 0\pmod 2$$

$$x^9+2x^7+3x^3+4x\equiv x+2x+0+4x\equiv 7x\equiv x\pmod 3$$

So, we have divisibility by $5$ and $2$ for all integers and divisibility by $3$ for those $x$ which are divisible by $3$. Hence, the expression is divisible by $30$ iff $x$ divisible by $3$

Comment: @BillDubuque: I've edited to answer OP's second question.